# Which Firebase javascript package should be used with React Native? The regular "Firebase Web SDK " or "react-native-firebase"?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Firebase Web SDK - https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase.

react-native-firebase - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase

My earlier understanding was that Web SDK might NOT offer all features in React Native. But now I'm facing a lot of crippling issues. I still haven't tried react-native-firebase.

One issues is that my project was working fine till last month. Now it shows errors when I try to write to firebase. The auth part works fine. Just the firestore gives error. Like so -

```
[Sun Apr 25 2021 19:43:33.243]  BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./prebuilt.rn-cf004e03.js from D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\index.js:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\prebuilt.rn-cf004e03.js(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\prebuilt.rn-cf004e03.js\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)    
> 1 | import firebase from '@firebase/app';
  2 | import '@firebase/util';
  3 | import '@firebase/logger';
  4 | import '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:271:42)
    at resolve (D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:571:33)
    at D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:587:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:586:33)      
    at D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\bareWorkflowRN\backup23\tester1PaymentsNPlacePicker\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

I was wondering if react-native-firebase would be helpful here, or if someone knows the solution to this issue.

I have tries the `cd android` and `gradlew clean` commands

Comment: you should definitely use react-native-firebase. The web SDK is written for a browser and react-native does not have some features offered by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As @LonelyCpp mentioned in comments you must use `react-native-firebase` which will give you more features and full features of React Native framework but `Firebase Web SDK` is only for native Javascript (Vanilla JS or Plain JS) which will works great for Web Browsers.